# Windows Forms DataGridViews' SelectionChanged event fired multiple times

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, selection

Here is my problem:

I have DataGridView. It's source is set to the BindingList of my business objects.
Business object implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Each time the business object changes DataGridView fires several SelectionChanged events. When I add/remove objects to the DataSource SelectionChanged events are fired too.

I want to use this event to update my view, but it looks horrible with so many events.

Can anyone help please?

Or maybe someone can help me with master-details scenario with DataGridView when binding to the list of business objects?

Comment: Have you tried checking the "source" of the SelectionChanged event? Check the type to see if it is something else triggering the event (chained calls). You could also use this information to only execute the event handler for the right caller/situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView selectionChanged event firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979149/datagridview-selectionchanged-event-firing-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment. I've made a little "investigation" and found out that BindingSource.PositionChanged event fits my scenario perfectly.
It is a bit painful to implement master/details scenario with the WinForms' data binding after trying WPF...

Comment: Hi @alekz , Could you please explain how did you resolved this issue. Because I got the same issue.